# rails -version command error in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, rails

I have installed ruby and rails in Ubuntu 12.04. I am trying to create the new project for rails using this command "rails new testApp", but it is giving me the error

```
  "/home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load
 such file -- /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rails-4.2.0/bin/rails
 (LoadError)"
```

. It is so ugly and pathetic to run the rails in windows so i switched to Ubuntu but here I am again facing difficulties.

Any help will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look in `.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rails`  at line 23

Change

```
gem 'rails', version
load Gem.bin_path('rails','rails', version)
```

to

```
gem 'rails', version
load Gem.bin_path('railties','rails', version)
```

Worked for me.